# Single Layout for all screen sizes

Tags: android

I have read many documentation on supporting multiple screen sizes but still confused.
I have read like if specified in dp it will get automatically scaled.

In my sample i just have a single layout. there i have placed an edit text.
and given width , suppose 170 dp. suppose width wise it is half the screen in a 5 inch phone emulator.

What i was expecting is, if i show it on an tablet 7inch or 10 inch , there also it will be half the width of the screen (i.e it will get automatically scaled). But it didnt.  in a 10 inch tablet it  is only very small size.

what should i do to achieve this only  through layout xml ( only single xml )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use layout weights, you can use them like a percentage of 100.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the textview takes up 50% of the screen width and the other view is a kind of invisible spacer taking up the other 50% of the screen width.

Which looks something like this (Eclipse XML preview):

[image: TextView wrapping at 50%]

As you can see the textview wraps when it gets to 50% of the screen. Working on all sizes of screen.

Comment: That does the trick . Thanks. What about the text size ? can we scale similarly that too.

Comment: Nope just use 'sp' for textsize

Comment: i have tried sp , but it has the same effect as i explained in my question. So  for text case i MUST create different styles for large and xlarge right ?? i cant acheive it using single xml !!

Comment: Yep have a look at styles.xml and the different params for screen sizes

Answer (score 2):

Dont set a Static width for the Textview as android will automatically scale it the the correct size using

```
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Basically what this does is makes the TextView the full size of the width of the device, and wraps the Height only to the needed height of the text.

YOu could also do warp_content for width to if you wanted. This is the best way. If you set it statically, you will need to create different layouts using XML.

Comment: Sorry but that doesnt answers my question. or is this a limitation.